# 19.10 Update to Latest Fails

Tags: updates, update-manager

I've read all the postings here including the one that said it was already answered and elsewhere for this apparently common problem but so far I have not been able to resolve it. The other answers did not help.

Typically I keep my systems up to date but this PC has been in storage for a year and a half during a remodel and now that it is back online, it needs to be updated/upgraded from the EOL 19.10 to 20.10 but it fails, then immediately wants to update again.

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease               
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Since the machine has been in storage for a long period, perhaps it would be expedient to simply reformat and reinstall a current version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Not a valid solution and not what I asked. Of course, if all else fails I’ll do that but this seems to be such a common problem that I’m surprised it exists at all. The only reason the PC was in storage is that that the home was being remodeled and it is still my primary Web development system and I don’t care to have to set all that up again.

Comment: That's why it's a comment rather than an answer.  Have you check the answers in [https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)